# canvas gradient in animation

Tags: html5-canvas

I’m having a problem with the rendering of the radial gradient; in fact only last colour of the gradient list of colours is rendered. The first three circles are animated. Is there any conflict between gradient and up-dating loop to render the animation?
Thanks
This is my code:

```
    <!doctype html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Disc and Animated-Circle</title>
    <style>
      #canvasOne {
         position: absolute;
            border: dotted 2px black;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -450px;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -250px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);
      function eventWindowLoaded() {
         canvasApp();
          }
      function canvasApp() {
      var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
      var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
              drawScreen();
      function drawScreen() {
         //translation to centre canvas
         context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
         var x = canvasOne.width/2;
         var y = canvasOne.height/2;
         var circleWidth = 100;
         var circleHeight = 100;
         context.translate(x+.5*circleWidth, y+.5*circleHeight);
                 context.save();
             //speed
         r += speed;
         //canvas
         context.fillStyle = "blue";
         context.fillRect(-(canvasOne.width/2+circleWidth/2), -(canvasOne.height/2+circleHeight/2), canvasOne.width, canvasOne.height);
         //circle 1
         context.strokeStyle = "#66f";
         context.lineWidth = 4;
         context.beginPath();
         context.arc(-circleWidth/2, -circleHeight/2, r,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360, false);
         context.closePath();
         //call circle 1
         context.stroke();
         context.restore();
         //circle 2
         context.strokeStyle = "#69f";
         context.lineWidth = 4;
         context.beginPath();
         context.arc(-circleWidth/2, -circleHeight/2, r+4,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360, false);
         context.closePath();
         //call circle 2
         context.stroke();
         context.restore(); 
         //circle 3
         context.strokeStyle = "#6cf";
         context.lineWidth = 4;
         context.beginPath();
         context.arc(-circleWidth/2, -circleHeight/2, r+8,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360, false);
         context.closePath();
         //call circle 3
         context.stroke();
         context.restore();
         //disc gradient
         var grad = context.createRadialGradient(100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100);
         grad.addColorStop(0, 'white');
         grad.addColorStop(.5, 'grey');
         grad.addColorStop(1, 'black');
         context.fillStyle = grad;
                 //disc
         context.beginPath();
         context.arc(-circleWidth/2, -circleHeight/2, 100, (Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360, false);
         context.closePath();
         //call disc
         context.fill();
      } //end drawScreen
    var speed = 20;
    var r = 100;
    setInterval(drawScreen, 200);
    } //end canvasApp
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <canvas id="canvasOne" width="900" height="500">
       Canvas is not supported.
   </canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the centre of the gradient at (100,100) which is not the centre of the circle.

Change the line

```
var grad = context.createRadialGradient(100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100);
```

to

```
var grad = context.createRadialGradient(-circleWidth/2, -circleHeight/2, 0, -circleWidth/2, -circleHeight/2, 100);
```